# Does .populate() perform any optimizations to reduce the number of queries sent to Mongo?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a function that uses Mongoose to populate 13 subdocuments on a model. The chained calls to populate look like this:

```
blogPost
  .populate({ path: 'author', model: 'User' })
  .populate({ path: 'blog', model: 'Blog' })
  ...
  .populate({ path: 'tags', model: 'Tags' },
    function (err, post) {
      processPost(post);
    }
  );
```

(in total there are 13 calles to .populate, including the final call which is given the callback that processes the blog post).

Will this call make >= 13 queries to Mongo, or does Mongoose have some kind of optimization techniques to minimize all the extra work that these statement may cause?

I checked this page of the Mongoose documentation, which didn't seem to include any discussion on the performance implications of using .populate multiple times.

So my question is: Does .populate() perform any optimizations to reduce the number of queries sent to Mongo?

Comment: I think if you are using that many `populate`s, you should reconsider your schema or Mongo altogether. Why not store the tags in an array within the document? You are treating it like a relational database, from the looks of it.